# Almost point-free style

Tags: terminology, functional-programming

Programmers often talk about point-free style. In contrast to the imperative style (pseudocode):

```
h := function(x) {
  y := f(x)
  z := g(y)
  return z;
}
```

one might write the following [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming):

```
h := f . g
```

where `.` is composition and the argument is now implicit. I'm wondering if there is a name for

```
h := function(x) {
  return g(f(x))
}
```

or

```
h := x -> g(f(x))
```

where there are no assignments, just a series of function calls. (They might be more complex than simple composition, though, like `h := x -> g(f(x), q(r(x), 1), x)`.) The only points are the arguments themselves, there are no intermediates and the entire function is essentially a return statement.

It seems like this is related but not identical to functional programming. What is it called? Are there references discussing it (as there are for functional and point-free programming)? I know it's popular in some languages more than others.

Comment: Are you passing around higher-order functions in your example there, or just returning the result of a function into another function?

Comment: Single expression/statement function?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I think it's just ordinary *function composition.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: More the latter, since the variables themselves are named. But there's no reason to exclude variadic input, nor higher-order functions called with an _a priori_ unknown number of arguments (though this would require variadic return values for some functions).

Comment: Yeah, that's just "function composition."  Or "non-point-free-style," if you like.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wouldn't refer to `x -> g(f(x), q(r(x), 1), x)` as *function composition*.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find that more readable than it's point-free counterpart.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Well, what is it then?  There doesn't have to be a "term" for it, necessarily.  Let's make this a real question and answer pair, and not just toss around terms.  I would love to learn more about this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suggested *single expression function* above, though that's not perfect either, since some languages consider blocks containing assignments expressions as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Can you expand that into a paragraph or two, rather than just three words, and write an answer?

Comment: @Charles: There's been a long and colorful debate on this site's Meta about the topicality of "Word Definitions."  In short, we're not a dictionary.  The question would be far more interesting if we discussed the relevant issue here (whatever that is), not send everyone off to Wikipedia with a new term to research.

Comment: I wouldn't call the first example imperative unless `f` and `g` aren't pure, but in that case `f . g` would be just as imperative. It's certainly not point-free, but it's not imperative either.

Comment: @Doval: You're right, I didn't really use the right term, _mea culpa_. Feel free to edit.

Comment: I dont think id call the first example imperative, its still funtional, just not point free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminology of the lambda calculus, the relation between `f` and `\x -> f(x)` is called [eta equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion). By the same reasoning, `f . g = \x -> (f . g)(x) = \x -> f(g(x))` could be called "practically" eta equivalent, if we inline the intermediate step of applying the function composition `(.)`.

Answer (score 6):

It's just an *expression*, or more specifically, a *lambda expression*.  Because of referential transparency, you can substitute a function's body or its result wherever it is called.  If you actually did this for an entire program, you'd see that every functional program is effectively a single large expression like your examples.  We just employ a lot of syntax to split it up and make it more modular and easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a distinct style, because once you allow functions with named parameters, it is easy to simulate named intermediate values by taking a lambda function and immediately invoking it.

Let me rewrite your first example into a language with an explicit skoped "let" construct, specifically Elm.  I'm replacing `f(x)` and `g(y)` with concrete silly computations, because there will be lots of function calls below and I don't want these to confuse things.

```
h_let(x) =
  let y = "foo of " ++ x in
    let z = "goo of " ++ y in
      z
```

#### Simulating `let`

This "let" is just syntax sugar, we can simulate it with lambda functions and function calls:

```
h_lambdas(x) =
  (\y ->
     (\z ->
        z
     )("goo of " ++ y)  
  )("foo of " ++ x)
```

(Many LISP dialects actually implement `let` as a macro, expanding to such a lambda call.)

But as you can see, it's very cumbersome that the values appear at the end, so nobody likes to use this style when they have a choice.
(In javascript, this coding style is known as [IIFE — Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression), and has been useful before ES6 modules.)

#### Fixing the cumbersome order

This manual simulation of `let` can be much less awkward languages with some kind of "pipeline" syntax, which lets you write something like `value |> func` instead of `func(value)`.  As it happens, Elm has an `|>` operator:

```
h_pipe(x) =
  "foo of " ++ x |> \y ->
    "goo of " ++ y |> \z ->
      z
```

Actually you don't even need syntax! Could also improve this with a tiny helper:

```
mylet(value, func) = func(value)

h_helper(x) =
  mylet("foo of " ++ x, \y ->
    mylet("goo of " ++ y, \z ->
      z
    )
  )
```

*Executable version of above examples: https://ellie-app.com/bj8rSK5R4w8a1*